# Intersection of stable and unstable manifolds.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, vector-fields, chaos-theory

Let $$\dot{x}=F(x)$$ be an *autonomous* (i.e. it does not depend on $t$) system with $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ a regular as you want vector field.

Suppose also that $0$ is an *hyperbolic* equilibrium point, meaning that the Jacobian $JF_{|0}$ only have eigenvalues with non-zero real part. In this case $W^+$ and $W^-$ as defined below are manifolds.

Denote $$W^+=\{x: \|\phi^tx\| \to 0, \ t \to +\infty\}$$ $$W^- =\{x: \|\phi^tx\| \to 0, \ t \to -\infty\}$$ where $\phi$ is the associated flux which exists by the existence and uniqueness of solutions for $\dot{x}=F(x).$ Consider $$W^+ \cap W^- = \{x: \|\phi^tx\| \to 0,  \ t \to \pm \infty\}.$$

> **Question 1:** I read from a trustworthy source that in this case it must be that $W^+ \cap W^- = \{0\},$ but I am failing to thoroughly convince myself of this fact. Can you show me a proof ?

Comment: Question 1: homoclinic orbits do exist in general (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoclinic_orbit) and so the answer is that there is no proof because it is false in general. But there cases in which the answer is positive: for example on the plane when there are no other equilibria.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but I also assume that the origin is an hyperbolic point of equilibrium.

Comment: @HarryAngstrom Would you mind disclosing your source?

Comment: Perhaps there are some other details in the course notes that would be useful to someone trying to help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the notes were talking about **local** stable and unstable manifolds.
Local stable and unstable manifolds are defined as the $x$ such that $\phi_t(x) \to x_0$ while remaining in a small neighborhood of the equilibrium point $x_0$ (as $t \to \pm \infty$).

These are (germs of) smooth manifolds intersecting each other transversally at $x_0$ (in the hyperbolic case). In particular,
$W_{loc}^u(x_0) \cap W_{loc}^s(x_0)=\{x_0\}$.

---

More details:

Local stable and unstable manifolds are diffeomorphic to balls of dimensions $p$ and $q$, where $p$ and $q$ are the number of eigenvalues with negative/real parts in the continuous time case, and $<1$ or $>1$ modulus in the discrete case. Moreover, they are tangent to the eigenspace of these eigenvalues. Basically, the local picture is the same as the linearized vector field/discrete map.

Comment: @HarryAngstrom I'm not sure I understand your question. In the case of the iterations of a diffeomorphism, the local stable and unstable manifolds only intersect at the fixed point, but the global stable/unstable manifolds can intersect elsewhere (as is the case for flows). The only difference is that for diffeomorphisms is that the global invariance of the set of intersection points will only give you a countable set in general.

Comment: @HarryAngstrom This is very strange... It is certainly possible for a discrete map coming from a flow (Poincaré section) to have intersections between (global) stable and unstable manifolds (this is known as a homoclinic intersection). Indeed, that was the case in the work of Poincaré that introduced the notion in the first place!

Answer (score 4):

There are many examples as you ask (in the comments). For example, for the equation
$$
(x,y)'=(y, x(x-2)(x-3))
$$
you get the phase portrait

[image]

Note the homoclinic orbit of the equilibrium $(3,0)$.

Comment: Sure, just make the computations.

Comment: That is a different question, unrelated to the one that you asked (I leave it as an exercise, since it depends on what you know). Incidentally, unless you reformulate your question, the answer that you accept doesn't answer it while mine does. Quite peculiar indeed.